# rails works locally, but server statut 304 on heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I render a partial via ajax in rails. Works great locally, but on heroku I get a 304 and nothing happens on the webpage : http://www.cremers.fr/articles/histoire

I first render all articles like so:

`all_finance.html.erb`:

```
<%= render 'articles' %>
```

then in the partial `_articles.html.erb`:

```rb
<% @articles.each do |a| %>
    <% if a.categorie == "histoire" %>
        <%= link_to "lire la suite", article_histoire_url(a.id), remote: true %>
    <% elsif a.categorie == "finance"  %>
        <%= link_to "lire la suite", article_finance_url(a.id), remote: true %> 
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

article_finance_url processes the action `article#finance`. 
`finance.js.erb`contains:

```
document.getElementById('trunc_article_<%= @article.id %>').remove();
document.getElementById('add_article_<%= @article.id %>').innerHTML = '<%= render("contenu") %>';
document.getElementById('add_link_<%= @article.id %>').innerHTML = '<%= link_to image_tag("partage.png", size: "20x20", class: "marge_ht"), article_finance_url(@article.id) %>';
```

`finance.html.erb`contains:

```
<%= render 'article' %>
```

Running this locally works fine. On heroku, the server responds the right content, i.e. `finance.js.erb` correctly rendered with the inbedded templates, but also give a 304 response.

Comment: Status 304 is not an error, it's a "not modified" response that tells the browser to use the cached version of whatever file it's requesting so it doesn't have to send the data again. You have some javascript errors shown on the browser's console, fix those errors first.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of posterity: In my case I have omitted closing paranthesis in on of the js files.